# increase efficiency of concurrent dictionary access c#

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, concurrency, locking

I have a list that is accessed by multiple background threads to update/read. Updates actions include both insertions and deletions.

To do this concurrently without synchronization problems, I am using a lock on a private readonly object in the class.

To minimize the time I need to lock the list when reading its data, I do a deep clone of it and return the deep clone and unlock the dictionary for insert/delete updates.

Due to this every read of the list increases the memory consumption of my service.

One point to note is that the inserts/deletes are internal to  the class that contains the list. But the read is meant for public consumption.

My question is:

Is there any way, I can avoid cloning the list and still use it concurrently for reads using read/write locks?

```
public class ServiceCache
    {
        private static List<Users> activeUsers;
        private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
        private static ServiceCache instance = new ServiceCache();

        public static ServiceCache Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        private void AddUser(User newUser)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                //... add user logic
            }
        }

        private void RemoveUser(User currentUser)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                //... remove user logic
            }
        }

        public List<Users> ActiveUsers
        {
            get
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    //The cache returns deep copies of the users it holds, not links to the actual data.
                    return activeUsers.Select(au => au.DeepCopy()).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If independent threads are deleting from their deep copy of the list, how to you ensure their work is meaningfully synchronized?

Comment: Eric, the deep copy is only meant to be used as a snapshot of the cache in time and changing it should not be reflected in the actual cache.

Comment: Side note: "To minimize the time ... I do a deep clone of it ": this is exact reason why phrase "premature optimization root of all evil" exists. Deep clone of any non-trivial object is unlikely to be a fast operation. You always should measure to understand what your "optimization" actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the `ConcurrentDictionary` class, and create a key for each of the `Users` objects you are storing. Then it becomes as simple as this for adding / updating a user:

```
_dictionary.AddOrUpdate("key", (k, v) =>
    {
        return newUser;
    }, (k, v) =>
    {
        return newUser;
    });
```

And then for removing, you would do this:

```
 Users value = null;
_dictionary.TryRemove("key", out value);
```

Getting the list of people would be super easy as well, since you would just need to do:

```
return _dictionary.Values.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Which should return a copy of the dictionary contents at that very moment.

And let the .NET runtime take care of the threading for you.

Comment: Actually, you can just return `.Values`, which is copy-on-read.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that! It makes total sense now that I read it =D

Answer (score 5):

You can use a reader-writer lock to allow simultaneous reads.

However, it would be much faster to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and thread-safe immutable values, then get rid of all synchronization.

Comment: Does it matter even if the lock is local to this class, but I am accessing the object it locks outside for reading?

Answer (score 1):

> Due to this every read of the list increases the memory consumption of
>   my service.

Why? Are the callers not releasing the reference? They need to, since the content of the dictionary can change.

What you are doing with copying is I think very close to how a Concurrent data structure, e.g. copy-on-write collection works, except that the caller cannot hold on to the reference.

A couple of other approaches:

- Return the same copy to all callers till the collection gets modified. The returned collection should be immutable
- Expose all the functionality the caller would want from the copy and use a single lock to work with the original list